# django queryset. How do i set a columns null value to bool false

Tags: django, django-queryset

i'm using a model based on a table view. When returned some column is off course null. But i want to assign all empty/null to bool value False.

Maybe there is another django way to assign all null/none to a bool False for a var used in filter

view.py

```
rows = Vbase.objects.all().values(*db_sel_columns) 
rows_filter = baseFilter(request.GET, queryset=rows)
```

models.py

```
inRU = models.BooleanField(_("inRU"), blank=False, null=False, default=False,max_length=3)
```

filters.py

```
inRU = django_filters.CharFilter(lookup_expr='iregex', label='', widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'this.form.submit();','color': 'navy','class': 'form-select'},choices=CHOICES_trueFalse))
```

When selecting in my template i can fine chose true, false, any. But i need to make all "none" to false.

can you help on this?
Thanks

Comment: Don't understand. It's a CharField so it can't be False or True. `blank=False` means it can't be stored blank either, and `null=False` means the same for null (None) values. Are you asking how to wrap Django around a pre-existing table with null values, and how to remove them?

Comment: changed model to correct usage. (maybe)

Comment: Default=False is wrong: your default value is what a newly created object gets if nothing specified otherwise, and it must be a character string for a CharField. Commonly, use null string `default=""` but sometimes a different "This was never set" value is appropriate. If the object is  being created via a form, set the form's initial value that you want in that circumstance  for this field, which will end up stored here if the user doesn't change it.